# How to manage multiple requests in GCE VM instance Without creating an instance group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, google-cloud-platform, puma

Timeout(502) errors are occurring while making more than one request on the server. I've got a solution load balancer. But, the load balancer would be needed (unmanaged / managed) VM instance group.

So, I am confusing that, **Load Balancer** will be managing multiple requests at the same time?

I am sending external https API requests along with these requests.
When I delete this external API request it works fine, but when
I send with an external API so the server can't handle the requests
And a timeout error is occurring.

Would you please help me to manage multiple requests on the server or give me another solution for the same? Thanks for advance!

Comment: Please update the question so that you give us more details, make it more comprehensible and focused. Creating the UNMANAGED instance group could be a big mistake, why did you think it will fix the issue ? is the issue scalability or the application?

Comment: The issue for scalability.

Answer (score 1):

Handling multiple requests does not depends on having multiple VM instances or just one. The main idea of having instance group is to have high availability in your service and not completely to handle multiple requests; therefore, using instance groups or a single VM depends on your app architecture and the features you want to add using instance groups.

A single instance will be able to handle multiple requests like an instance group will do, I believe the multiple connections handling is something you need to check in your web server app (Apache or Nginx).

**Load balancers** are meant to handle multiple requests. So using **Load balancers** to handle multiple connections depends on your architecture, if you have multiple backends you have to use a load balancer, if you are using a single backend then your web server will do the job.

The 502 error message can be related with several things, [here are a few from Google's page](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#what_is_logged):

- backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client
- backend_early_response_with_non_error_status
- backend_interim_response_not_supported
- backend_response_corrupted
- backend_response_headers_too_long
- backend_timeout
- failed_to_connect_to_backend
- failed_to_pick_backend

In order to try to fix 502 message you must use the values that Google mention [in this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#timeouts_and_retries) to configure Keep alive timeouts for common web server software like Apache and Nginx.

I believe that your issue is related with configuration in your web server and you are approaching it in a wrong way using load balancers and instance groups.